# Efficient way to populate Entify Framework query with related objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship

I'm using EF for a set of objects and want to query one type of object with the matching entries from two other tables.  This is to dump the query into an XML output.  At first, used a join since in the original data each *Employee* always had 1+ instances of a *Computer* object (solution #2 below), but it's not necessarily true.

For purpose here, imagine:

- an *Employee* object,
- each Employee has an *EmployeeType* (a few fixed entries) and
- each Employee has *zero* or more *Computer* objects (typically 0-3).
- each Computer belongs to one Employee, not all Employee has a Computer.
- each Employee has a criteria on which the search is based (such as *Division*).

So I saw several possible solutions:

1. Use the *Employee.Computer.Load()* within a loop, but with 10,000+ rows, that causes an enormous performance penalty.
2. Use a *join* in the query, but that leaves out all *Employees* that do not have a *Computer*.
3. Use Linq to Entities, <strike>but that seems to have the overhead of #1: when loading *Computer*s it hits the database for EACH *Employee*</strike>.
4. Use a second query (all *Computer*s with matching *Computer.Employee.Division*), then in the *Employee* loop, add any *Computer* for the given employee.   While implementing this, I found that just running the second query (with *ToList()*) the EF populates the correct *Employee.Computer* lists with the objects I need.

Here, #4 loads the data with only 2 database hits instead of 10k+, and the EntityFramework actually collates the objects and creates all of the relationships.

***My Questions***:

- With #4, is the fact that the EF populates the *Employee.Computer* list something on which I can I rely?  If so, can you point me to the documentation?
- Is there a better way than #4?

***UPDATE***:
Well, bugger.  Sorry, but I simply blew it.  I was focusing on the
relationship with the "Computer" table and missed the fact that I
had an explicit *Employee.EmployeeTypeReference.Load()* w/o first testing 
for null, so the "Computer" list was a complete non-issue.

I only found this when running some performance tests and adding
Craig's solution to the mix.  In truth, the records aren't "Employees"
and "Computers" but abstractions, and I (conditionally) include every
field in the XML output, but they're small: a Name, ID(PK) and ID(FK)
plus an INT on the "Employee" table.  So, my presumption was that the
performance would be similar since the EF would create objects not
much heavier than the projection.

Anyway, here are the results wher the "Elapsed" time was 
the difference before this query and after the resultant XML was created.

- Case 1: Same as #2, but with *Include()* statements:

  `list = ve.Employee.Include("Computer").Include("EmployeeType").Where(e => e.Division.ID == divId).OrderBy(e => e.Name);`

  Elapsed: 4.96, 5.05
- Case 2: Uses in-line *Load()*:

  `list = ve.Employee.Where(e => e.Division.ID == divId).OrderBy(e => e.Name);`

  Elapsed: 74.62
- Case 3: Same as #4, but with *Include()* statements:

  `list = from e in ve.Employee.Include("Computer").Include("EmployeeType")
          where e.Division.ID == divId 
          orderby e.Name select e;`

  Elapsed: 4.91, 5.47
- Case 4: Uses in-line *Load()*:

  `list = from e in ve.Employee where e.Division.ID == divId orderby e.Name select e;`

  Elapsed: 74.20
- Case 5: Use *Include("EmployeeType") and separate "Computer" query, let EF associate:

  `elist = ve.Employee.Include("EmployeeType").Where(te => te.Division.ID == divId).OrderBy(e => e.Name).ToList();
  alist = ve.Alias.Where(a => a.Employee.Division.ID == divId).ToList();`

  Elapsed: 4.50, 4.02
- Case 6: Craig's suggestion of projections:

  `elist = from te in ve.ThesaurusEntry where te.Division.ID==divID
          orderby te.Name select new {
               ID = te.ID, Name = te.Name,
               Type = te.EmployeeType.Name,
               Freq = te.Frequency,
               Aliases = from a in te.Alias
               select new {
                  ID = a.ID, Name = a.Name
               }
           };`

  Elapsed: 0.73, 1.25

**Conclusions**

*Load()* is expensive, so use **Include()** or at least test with *IsLoaded*

Projection is a bit tedious, but significantly faster than EF fix-up. *[with this limited testing on "narrow" tables]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob's solution will work (+1), but if you don't need all of the fields in, say, Employee and Computer, I'd *strongly* recommend projecting instead:

```
var q = from e in Context.Employees
        where e.Division.Id = divisionId
        select new
        {
            Name = e.Name,
            EmployeeType = e.EmployeeType.Description,
            ComputerIds = from c in e.Computers
                          select new 
                          {
                              Id = c.Id
                          }
        };
```

Here you get all you need in one query, but *nothing more*: All the fields you don't need won't be returned.

You could probably even select into `XElement`s and just save the resulting tree rather than manually converting to XML. I haven't tried this, but it seems like it should work.

Regarding #4, yes, you can rely on this, but it's always good to check `IsLoaded` before calling `Load()`.

Comment: W.r.t. relying on #4 - do you know a reference?  I've coded it so that it will *Load()* if not *IsLoaded*, so it won't break -- performance will just tank, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you can indicate that the relations can be pre-loaded

```
Dim employees = From emp in db.Employees.Include("Computer") _
                Select emp
```

Comment: Indeed, that was #3, the problem was elsewhere -- but I didn't explicitly state that I'd used *Include()*, sorry.